# Python Pandas - increment matching rows by 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code where a dataframe d has two columns with col1 of strings values and col2 with int values.

I want to find all the rows matching to a pattern (using contains) and then increase the col2 values by 1 for the corresponding row. In the last line of my code where I am trying to increment by one I am getting following error:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   self[name] = value

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['abc', 'ave','abd', 'ave','abe', 'ave'], 'col2': [0,1,0,1,0,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#print(df[df.col1.str.contains("ab")])

df[df.col1.str.contains("ab")].col2 +=1
```

How can I increment the value using vector operation. I am trying to avoid for loop.

Comment: what do you want your output to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let this:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1.str.contains('ab').astype(int) + df.col2
```

Or

```
df['col2'] += df.col1.str.contains('ab').mul(1)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0  abc     1
1  ave     1
2  abd     1
3  ave     1
4  abe     1
5  ave     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Both work fine. Could you please explain the first solution briefly?

Comment: Sure.. You look at the col1 series use .str accessor with the contains method to check to see if 'ab' contained in that string,  if so the method returns True.  Then, you can use astype to cast True to integer equal to 1.  Now, add 1 back to the value in Col2.   The second works the same except, instead of using astype to a cast as integer, I multiply by integer 1 and implicit casting happens and returns integer 1.

Answer (score 3):

for fun:-)

```
pd.to_numeric(df.col1.replace({'ab':1},regex=True),errors='coerce').fillna(0)+df.col2
Out[16]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
dtype: float64
```